# how to call this method to read the SQLite data?

Tags: sql, objective-c, methods, cal

how to call this method?

```
   - (NSMutableArray*) readDataFromDatabase
```

and this--->

```
   - (void)inserisciValoriDaDB:(NSArray *)insert :(NSString *)sqlAdd
```

Comment: Please specify and add more context to your question, in order for us to help you. (You call a method in your viewcontroller like so, if that is what you want: [self YOURMETHOD])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [self readDataFromDatabase];

[self inserisciValoriDaDB:yourarray add:yourstring];
```